# Why can a use block not safely initialize a var?

Tags: kotlin, autocloseable

Why does this give a compile error?

```
val autoClosable = MyAutoClosable()
var myVar: MyType
autoClosable.use {
    myVar= it.foo()
}
println(myVar) // Error: Variable 'myVar' must be initialized
```

Maybe the compiler just sees `{ myVar= it.foo() }` as a function that is passed to another function and has no knowledge about when or even if it will be executed?

But since `use` is not just a function but Kotlin's replacement for Java's try-with-resource, some special knowledge about it would be appropriate, wouldn't it? Right now, I am forced to initialize `myVar` with some dummy value, which is not in the spirit of Kotlin at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `use { ... }` is not a language construct but [is just a library function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/use.html), the compiler doesn't know (and, currently, does not make effort to prove) that the lambda you pass is **ever executed**. Therefore the usage of the variable that might not be initialized is prohibited.

For example, compare your code to this function call. Without additional code analysis, they are identical for the compiler:

```
inline fun ignoreBlock(block: () -> Unit) = Unit

var myVar: MyType
ignoreBlock { myVar = it.foo() }
println(myVar) // Expectedly, `myVar` stays uninitialized, and the compiler prohibits it
```

To bypass this restriction, you can use the value returned from `use` (this is the value your block returns) to initialize your variable:

```
val myVar = autoClosable.use {
    it.foo()
}
```

And if you also want to handle the exception it might throw, then use [`try` as an expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html#try-is-an-expression):

```
val myVar = try {
    autoClosable.use {
        it.foo()
    }
} catch (e: SomeException) {
    otherValue   
}
```

Theoretically, inline functions can actually be checked to invoke a lambda exactly once, and if the Kotlin compiler could do that, it would allow your use case and some others. But this has not been implemented yet.

Comment: if it is lazy why this code can't working? `var myVar: MyType ;val b = { println(myVar) }; myVar = autoClosable.foo()`， Otherwise, there's my down-vote. :)

Comment: @holi-java, and why should it work? It's much easier for the compiler to prohibit `val b = { println(myVar) }` (which can be called **before** `myVar` is assigned -- `myVar` is unitialized up to the moment `b` is created) than to check that at each call site of `b` the `myVar` has already been initialized.

Comment: @holi-java, if that's not what you were asking about, then I must have misunderstood you, could you please reformulate the question?

Comment: Hi, you ask me to post it as question?

Comment: but it should be initialized `myVar` with `ObjectRef` since as you said the lambda is lazily, the compiler can't be sure the lambda is invoked.

Comment: we know any language such as javascript, the function can access the variable out side of its scope, and can be initialized later. but in java if you want both to write the value out of the lambda scope & read the value in lambda scope, we must using an `ObjectRef`. since the variable out of the lambda scope is **effective-final**. and I also can see the kotlin bytecode that the type  exactly  is a `ObjectRef`. why can't be compiled?

Comment: @holi-java, well, it's just how it works under the hood, but look at the semantics of the code. When you write `println(myVar)`, you expect the value of `MyType` to be printed, not the `ObjectRef` the compiler created to store that. Actually, the compiler makes everything to make a variable wrapped into an `ObjectRef` look like an ordinary `var`, the `ObjectRef` is never shown to the user (unless they look into the bytecode). So, by saying *`myVar` stays uninitialized*, I mean, *either the local variable or the `ObjectRef` wrapper doesn't hold the value that should be assigned*.

Comment: Actually, in my answer I abstract away from the `ObjectRef`, which is completely an implementation detail and is not necessary to explain the code semantics -- we can just think of the `var` as a container for a variable, no matter if it is wrapped or not, the compiler makes sure we assign the value before using the `var`.

Comment: hi, the first time I also think it is lazily. but when I dump the code, I found I can't say it is lazily correctly.I think you should give the thoroughly answer. :)

Comment: invoke the lambda exactly **once**. so what's wrong of my answer, sir?

Comment: What do you mean by **lazy**? The actual reason for the restriction the OP faced is that the compiler does not prove that the lambda is ever called. Once the *exactly-once* check I mentioned is implemented in the compiler, the code in the question will be allowed.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not good at english. I said I also found the lambda is lazily, but when I dump the byte code, I found I can't say it is lazily correctly. since the byte code of the lambda body is analyzed by compiler. **lazy** I means the code in lambda body is never invoked, if the lambda is not called.

Comment: sir, due to my bad english, I have create it as a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45243255/why-the-variable-cant-be-initialized-correctly-in-inline-function-as-in-java). I'm glad you to go to help me solve my confusion. first, thanks.

Comment: Regarding the original answer: Great! Writing it this way, you can even omit the explicit type declaration `MyType`. You might want to edit your answer.

Answer (score -1):

In case an exception occurs while executing `it.foo()`, the `use` block will catch the exception, close your `autoClosable`, and then return. In this case, `myVar` will be left uninitialized.

This is why the compiler won't let you do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Actually, `use` re-throws the exception it catches. If an exception is thrown inside the `use { ... }` block, it is thrown outside the `use` call, and the `println(myVar)` line is not reached at all. A *perfect compiler* would not prohibit this code because it would guess that `use` calls the block exactly once and rethrows the exception back into the calling code. :) The Kotlin compiler just does perform the *exactly-once* analysis for the lambdas.

Comment: Oh, right, I didn't check that. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score -1):

This is because `use` is an **inline function**, which means the lambda body will be inlined to the call-site function, and the actual type of the variable `myVar` depends on its context.

**IF** the `myVar` is used in lambda for reading, the the type is `MyType` or its supertype. for example:

```
//      v--- the actual type here is MyType
var myVar: MyType = TODO()

autoClosable.use {
    myVar.todo()
}
```

**IF** the `myVar` is used in lambda for writing, the actual type is an `ObjectRef`. why? this is because Java don't allow you change the variable out of the annoymous class scope. In fact, `myVar` is **effectively-final**. for example:

```
//  v--- the actual type here is an ObjectRef type.
var myVar: MyType

autoClosable.use {
    myVar = autoClosable.foo()
}
```

**So** when the compiler checking at `println(myVar)`, it can't sure the element of the `ObjectRef` is initialized or not. then a compiler error is raised.

**IF** you catch anything, the code also can't be compiled, for example:

```
//  v--- the actual type here is an ObjectRef type.
var myVar: MyType
try {
    autoClosable.use {
        myVar = it.foo()
    }
} catch(e: Throwable) {
    myVar = MyType()
}

//       v--- Error: Variable 'myVar' must be initialized
println(myVar)
```

**But** when the actual type of the `myVar` is `MyType`, it works fine. for example:

```
var myVar: MyType
try {
    TODO()
} catch(e: Throwable) {
    myVar = MyType()
}

println(myVar) // works fine
```

**Why** kotlin didn't optimize inline functions to use `MyType` directly for writing?

the only thing I think, the compiler don't know the `myVar` whether is used in lambda body of another uninline function in future. or kotlin want to keep semantic consistent for all of the functions.

Comment: The difference between `use` and `try` is that `try` is a language construct with a known semantics: it will execute the body, and if an exception is thrown, then it will execute the corresponding `catch` block. The compiler can thus prove that `myVar` is assigned by all means. And `use` is a completely different matter: it is just a library function, and it can manage the lambda it is passed in an arbitrary way (e.g. call it multiple times or never call it). Therefore the compiler cannot be sure that the code block is ever executed, and it conservatively prohibits possibly incorrect code.

Comment: well, but the code of the lambda body is inlined into call-site function, so it should be right. that I also have test it, nested `try-catch` also can working. but inline function can't. for example:  `try { try{ TODO() }catch(e:Throwable){throw e} } catch (e: Throwable) { myVar=autoClosable.foo() }`

Comment: so why the inlined function can't working, the only thing I can think is compiler don't sure the `element` of the `ObjectRef` is initialized. and I describe it in answer at the middle. maybe you never see it.

Comment: Even though the lambda is inlined, the control flow is not currently analyzed in it. It's just not implemented, and the compiler just prohibits this code as if the lambda is not called. To make it work, the compiler should analyze either the inline function body to prove that it calls the lambda or the resulting bytecode. Neither is done at this moment.

Comment: Also, when a `var` is used only in inline lambdas, it is not wrapped into an `ObjectRef` at all.

Comment: could you give some source code or some reference let me to see it? I know you have contributed Kotlin. but your answer don't persuade me at the first time.

Comment: Ok, sure, I'll do it a little bit later.